# Custom MaGGI Macro in Latex

Tags: macros, enumerate

When using a calculator in my school, we have to note it in a specific way. It‘s called the MaGGI-concept, which is made up of four pieces: **Ma**thematical idea, **G**raphic calculator input, **G**raphic calculator output, and **I**nterpretation. What‘s special about it, is the intentation. Both Gs have to be offset by „one tab“.

[image]

I tried to build something like this with the `enumerate` package, but I couldn’t get it to work. How can I make a custom macro for this?

For example:

```tex
\begin{maggi}
\ma LOREM
\g IPSUM
\g DOLOR
\i SIT
\end{maggi}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `\@hangfrom`, you couldn't use a `\par` token (or two consecutive new lines) inside this environment this way.

Also you might want to change the definition of `\maggicmd` (or don't use it at all) if you want to.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newlength\maggi@indent
\setlength\maggi@indent{1cm}
\newcommand*\MAggi{\PackageError{maggi}{Don't use me outside of the maggi environment}{}}
\newcommand*\maGgi{\PackageError{maggi}{Don't use me outside of the maggi environment}{}}
\newcommand*\magGi{\PackageError{maggi}{Don't use me outside of the maggi environment}{}}
\newcommand*\maggI{\PackageError{maggi}{Don't use me outside of the maggi environment}{}}
\newenvironment{maggi}
  {%
    \def\MAggi{\par\bigskip\@hangfrom{\makebox[\maggi@indent][l]{Ma:}}}%
    \def\maGgi{\par\medskip\@hangfrom{\kern\maggi@indent\makebox[\maggi@indent][l]{G:}}}%
    \let\magGi\maGgi
    \def\maggI{\par\medskip\@hangfrom{\makebox[\maggi@indent][l]{I:}}}%
  }
  {%
    \par\bigskip
    % the following will supress paragraph indentation if you don't put an empty
    % line after \end{maggi}
    \@endpetrue
  }
\makeatother
\newcommand\maggicmd[1]{\operatorname{\mathsf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\blindduck[-]
\begin{maggi}
  \MAggi I want to find the intersection between $f$ and $g$
  \maGgi $Y_1 = x^2$\\
         $Y_2 = 4$\\
         $\maggicmd{intersect}(Y_1, Y_2, \text{Guess next to }-2)$\\
         $\maggicmd{intersect}(Y_1, Y_2, \text{Guess next to }2)$
  \magGi $(-2|4)$\\
         $(2|4)$
  \maggI The graphs of $f$ and $g$ have two intersections. One in $(-2|4)$ and
         one in $(2|4)$.
\end{maggi}
\blindduck[-]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I became an environment!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!